# Is EF worth it for me

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ado.net

I've got a project I'm going to start.  There will probably be less than 10 tables.  ASP.NET MVC.  I have next to no experience with EF, but a great deal of experience with ADO.net and SQL.  Is it worth it for me to go with EF, or just use ADO.NET and write the code for the object mapping?

Comment: Do you need user to login? If yes, how do you plan for Authentication and Authorization?

Comment: yes, there will be user logins.  I plan on using ef for the login mechanism.  Just modifying the existing template code for my purposes

Answer (score 0):

> there will be user logins.

Since the application requires user login, you might want to consider using *ASP.NET Identity* rather than reinventing the wheel such as hashing algorithms.

ASP.NET Identity uses Entity Framework, but it doesn't require you to know EF. Since your project will be using EF, it is better to learn EF and use it instead of ADO.NET.

Comment: Yes, I will be using mainly built in methods for logins/roles.  The main issue is the heart of the program.

Comment: EF should not be issue; I would suggest go ahead and use it. I have a couple of sample projects - [one](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetCoreActiveDirectoryStarterKit) and [two](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin) - in GitHub which uses EF; you are feel free to use those source codes.  If you have any question, then come and ask in SO.